# Is there a single word which means "comatose with pleasure"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Prompted by [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/93401/20774) to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93396/in-what-story-does-a-worldwide-computer-reduce-human-intelligence-in-order-to-ma) on another stack, is there a single word which means

> "**to become comatose with pleasure**"

(i.e. where you experience so much euphoria that you literally become incapable of movement)?

Comment: Because the French have a frickin word for *every single possible* spiritual malady, we are happily equipped with "***[la petite morte](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_petite_mort)***" (or *the little death* if you're a die-hard anglophone). You might also consider *bask*, as in "*basking in the afterglow*".

Comment: Are you sure you mean "literally incapable of movement"?

Comment: @CanisLupus In my case? Absolutely (though, granted, temporarily).

Comment: @CanisLupus - Maybe you're not doing it right :-)

Comment: @Dan Bron--La petite mort (no e) is a euphemism for orgasm.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_petite_mort

Comment: @StevenLittman I know, brother, I know (see my second comment, in response to Canis Lupus). But read the 3rd paragraph of that Wikipedia article: its meaning has been extended to non-sexual situations.

Comment: That example was over 100 years old.  I don't think it's used much that way now.  I'd avoid extending it...

Comment: I decided to vote this down for "exaggeration". Surely it's not coma-inducing.

Comment: Hmmm... *catatonicated*?

Comment: I think *stoned* would work :)

Comment: “Euphoriætherised”?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think ***[ecstatic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ecstatic)*** may suggest the *"comatose-like"* state you are referring to:

> - in a trancelike state of great rapture or delight. (Collins Dict.)

Comment: What would you call a magical pill that induced ecstasy (I mean other than *Ecstasy*, obviously)?

Comment: I'd call it *Soma*, although that didn't cause paralysis per se in BNW

Comment: I think this is probably the closest I'll get.

Answer (score 6):

I have been *[narcotized](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narcotize)* with pleasure:

> transitive verb
>   1
>   a :  to treat with or subject to a narcotic
>   b :  to
>   put into narcosis
>
> 2 :  to soothe to unconsciousness or unawareness
>   *<sub>merriam-webster</sub>*

This assumes the secondary meaning of *[comatose](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/comatose)*:

> 1.1 humorous Extremely lethargic or sleepy:
>   *she lay comatose in the sun listening to a personal stereo*
>   *<sub>ODO</sub>*

I remember a time when I was experiencing some scary chest pains. After the doctor ruled out a heart attack, he decided morphine was the best temporary treatment--until they could get at the root of the problem. What a pleasant experience I had, but it was always so short lived, because I was so relaxed I fell asleep!

Any pleasure has the potential to become a *[narcotic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/narcotic)* for the human mind:

> noun
>
> 1 An addictive drug affecting mood or behavior, especially an illegal
>   one:
>   *<sub>ODO</sub>*

If we overload on any mind-altering activity, we loose touch!

From the poem *Narcotized* in *[A Whole Bunch of Words](https://books.google.com/books?id=I8KmCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA126&dq=%22narcotized%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vraJVbaJFILXsAXpo7PABQ&ved=0CEMQ6AEwCTgU#v=onepage&q=%22narcotized%22&f=false)* by Jon Glenn:

> The early morning sun shines in through a dusty basement window. Now
>   that the night is gone, my day can go on like the last one. I get up
>   on my world, I feel like I slept on pins and needles. The air is cold
>   and damp; I careen By way of my perception...
>
> I drift along in a daze; I feel as if I have been narcotized. I
>   remember the way as I regress in to a photograph.

Comment: Surely narcotic means "sleep inducing", rather than "pleasure inducing"?

Comment: Surely that is the point of the word *comatose*. The notion was *pleasure induced* rather than *pleasure inducing*. In this use, *pleasure* becomes the metaphoric narcotic.

Comment: I'm not feeling it. Drowsiness doesn't necessarily imply **extremes of pleasure.**

Comment: Have you ever been treated for pain with a narcotic, Richard? It's an ineffably pleasant experience, but too much will just put you too sleep!

Comment: @ScotM Add that additional detail to your answer, it's relevant and helpful! +1 either way.

Comment: I was thinking more "[wirehead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirehead_(science_fiction)) dialled up to 11"